# CSS Box-Shadow not shown on position relative

Tags: html, css

I have this css for the outer `div`:

```
#outer{    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and this one for the inner which should give a box-shadow, but it doesn't:

```
#inner{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 32px 88px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="outer">
     <header >
            <!-- some section -->
     </header>
     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>
     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>

     <h1>Text text text</h1>

     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>

            <!-- THIS HERE would be the shaddow -->
     <div id="inner"></div>
     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>
 </div>
```

As you can see I have tried some things with `transform` and `z-index`, but nothing seems to work.

```css
#outer{    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#inner{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 32px 88px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
     <header >
            <!-- some section -->
     </header>
     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>
     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>

     <h1>Text text text</h1>

     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>

            <!-- THIS HERE would be the shaddow -->
     <div id="inner"></div>
     <section >
            <!-- some section -->
     </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: yes it won't show because there is no HTML

Comment: can you please add your html code also

Comment: and one more thing your alpha value is low. So increase your alpha value and check it

Comment: @TemaniAfif I added the html

Comment: @ManojA I added the html.
Also I have tested the shadow somewhere else already and the shadow is visible.

Comment: it's working fine, maybe because you used a very low opacity and not able to see it

Comment: its working in your code. you have to try to reduce you box-shadow values like            box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);

Comment: @TemaniAfif As I said, thats not the problem - i have moved the div somewhere else and gave it position: absolute and the shadow was clearly visible

Comment: @ManojA Didnt work. Solved it with a workaround, but would still like to know why it didnt work at all

Comment: the code you added is working fine but maybe there is more CSS used, so if you can show us all the code it will be usefull

Comment: i agree @TemaniAfif 's reply. its working fine

Answer (score 2):

It's because your blur-radius is so high and your opacity is so low.

Change this: `box-shadow: 0px 32px 88px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);`

To something like this: `box-shadow: 0px 32px 10px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

```css
#outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#inner {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 32px 10px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <header>
    <!-- some section -->
  </header>
  <section>
    <!-- some section -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <!-- some section -->
  </section>

  <h1>Text text text</h1>

  <section>
    <!-- some section -->
  </section>

  <!-- THIS HERE would be the shaddow -->
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <section>
    <!-- some section -->
  </section>
</div>
```

Just tweak these two values to how you want.